# Getting a Compiling error that won't let the apk run

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling

**I'm getting these two errors while building my Kotlin project:**

Unresolved reference: v7
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

I have tried cleaning and building my project again but there's no effect.

```
    package com.ritika.pokemonand

   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity //error in this line
   import android.os.Bundle
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

   import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
```

Comment: You're apparently using androidx, so you don't need the v7 `AppCompatActivity`. Just delete that line.

Comment: @MikeM. it worked, was in problem for quite a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when migrate to androidX or copy paste code from old project in androidX project.

So just remove this line

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

And add this (if not exist)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```